# which row min value came from (vertical coalesce)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to find out row ID that the values come from while doing GROUP BY.

first create and populate a "play object"

```
-- vertical coalesce with row-source of value :) instead of column-source of value as in horizontal coalesce :)
CREATE TABLE #TBL(ID INT, GR INT, A INT, B INT)
INSERT INTO #TBL
SELECT 1,1,1,NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 2,1,NULL,2
UNION ALL SELECT 3,1,NULL,3
UNION ALL SELECT 4,2,2,NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 5,2,NULL,NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 6,2,6,NULL
```

selecting minimum values is simple:

```
SELECT GR, MIN(A) A, MIN(B) B,
    'Which first available row did A come from?' A_ID, 
    'Which first available row did B come from?' B_ID 
FROM #TBL
GROUP BY GR
```

but to answer the questions is not!

I've tried to do subquery, but since values are coming from different rows it doesn't work:

```
SELECT a.*
from #TBL a
    join (
    SELECT GR, MIN(A) A, MIN(B) B,
        'Which row did A come from?' A_ID, 
        'Which row did B come from?' B_ID
    FROM #TBL
    GROUP BY GR) b on a.GR = b.GR and a.A = b.A and a.B = b.B
--DROP TABLE #TBL
```

Please help.

Comment: You could join twice, once for A_ID and once for B_ID

Comment: This would be so much easier if you use two queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if it will out perform joins/outer applies (I think it will), but this will work:

```
WITH CTE AS
(   SELECT  GR, 
            A, 
            B, 
            ID, 
            MinA = MIN(A) OVER(PARTITION BY GR), 
            MinB = MIN(B) OVER(PARTITION BY GR)
    FROM    #TBL
)
SELECT  GR,
        A = MIN(A),
        B = MIN(B),
        A_ID = MIN(CASE WHEN MinA = A THEN ID END),
        B_ID = MIN(CASE WHEN MinB = B THEN ID END)
FROM    CTE
GROUP BY GR;
```

On this small sample the statistics point to this performing better:

**Using Aggregates**

> (estimated) Query Cost 13%
>
> Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 3, logical reads 21, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

**Using OUTER APPLY**

> (estimated) Query Cost 87%
>
> Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 16, logical reads 42, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

But you may find real examples with indexes will be different.

Comment: +1 I like this answer. Though it hardly can there be a test with 3 rows.

Comment: 100% agree about the testing, and IO statistics and estimated query costs are not the be all and end all. There is no comparison to actual tests on real data.

Comment: thanks a lot. Works like a charm. what prompted me to select this post as an answer is possibility of easy scale. If I needed another column to be included, it is as simple as adding a couple of lines :) instead of another OUTER APPLY. Performance wise the CTE is the winner by a huge margin on a roughly half a mill original rows. Thumps up!

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT 
        T1.GR,
        T2.A,
        T3.B,
        T2.ID A_ID,
        T3.ID B_ID
FROM #TBL T1
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 *
             FROM #TBL
             WHERE GR = T1.GR
             AND A IS NOT NULL
             ORDER BY A, ID) T2
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 *
             FROM #TBL
             WHERE GR = T1.GR
             AND B IS NOT NULL
             ORDER BY B, ID) T3
```

Results:

```
╔════╦═══╦══════╦══════╦══════╗
║ GR ║ A ║  B   ║ A_ID ║ B_ID ║
╠════╬═══╬══════╬══════╬══════╣
║  1 ║ 1 ║ 2    ║    1 ║ 2    ║
║  2 ║ 2 ║ NULL ║    4 ║ NULL ║
╚════╩═══╩══════╩══════╩══════╝
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH CTEA AS
(   SELECT  ID, GR, A, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY GR ORDER BY A) AS 'RowNum'
    FROM    #TBL where A is not null
),    CTEB AS
(   SELECT  ID, GR, B, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY GR ORDER BY B) AS 'RowNum'
    FROM    #TBL where B  is not null
)
select  CTEA.GR, CTEA.A, CTEA.ID, CTEB.B, CTEB.ID
  from  CTEA 
  jull  outer join  CTEB
    on  CTEA.GR = CTEB.GR
   and  CTEA.RowNum = 1 
   and  CTEB.RowNum = 1
```

Comment: Oh, and to clarify my previous comment, this happens because `ORDER BY A` orders `NULL` values first than non `NULL` values

Comment: I think that you now need a `FULL JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN`, since you are returning only one row currently (because there should be one where `B` is null). And sorry if this seems like I'm picking on you

Comment: @Lamak No problem,  I agree